# Remove Binary data from PHP debug backtrace

Tags: php, debugging, binary, trace

We like to print a stack trace when things go wrong. We can do that easily with PHP using debug_backtrace. However the problem is, when things like File upload or Image upload goes wrong we get a huge Binary file also as part of trace. Like this: (truncated)

```
 #webgloo_ajax_error_handler() called at :0
1175 array (
1176   0 => 256,
1177   1 => 'Image_upload_error',
1178   2 => '/home/rjha/code/github/sc/webgloo/lib/com/indigloo/media/ImageUpload.php',
1179   3 => 95,
1180   4 =>
1181   array (
1182     'prefix' => 'test/2012/04/08/',
1183     'fieldName' => '120444-LM_menu_button.png',
1184     'sBlobData' => '<89>PNG^M
1185 ^Z
1186 ' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '^MIHDR' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . 'P' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0"      . '^^^H^F' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '»C<99>±' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '^AsRGB' . "\0" . '®Î^\é'      . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '^FbKGD' . "\0" . 'ÿ' . "\0" . 'ÿ' . "\0" . 'ÿ ½§<93>' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . ''      . "\0" . ' pHYs' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '^K<88>' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '^K<88>^Aå<8e>)I' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' .      "\0" . '^GtIME^GÚ^B^R^V 5$=fÞ' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '^PEIDAThÞÝ<9a>û<8f>]WuÇ?k<9f>sgl<8f>Ç<89>íøAH^P8<89>±<9d>8
```

Ideally I would like to remove such Binary blobs from my back trace. Is there a way to reliably detect binary strings in PHP?

Following does **not** work for me. Mostly because I want the solution to be exhaustive.

1. Filtering based on names (like exclude .PNG)
2. Looking for magic "numbers" inside each data piece

Here is my current backtrace generator

```
function backtrace() {
            fwrite($this->fhandle," ---- __backtrace__  ----- \n" );
            $trace = debug_backtrace();
            $message = '' ;

            foreach ($trace as $i=>$t) {
                $message = sprintf("#%d %s%s%s() called at %s:%d \n", 
                    $i,$t['class'], $t['type'],$t['function'],$t['file'],$t['line']);
                fwrite($this->fhandle,$message);

                $args = $t['args'];

                if(!empty($args)) {
                    //remove blob strings from Argument
                    Util::unsetInArray($args,array('sBlobData','tBlobData'));
                    $this->dump($args);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: I presume by binary you mean data containing [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters).
Since plaintext commonly includes some of those (\t\n\r ...) you only want a certain range:
    preg_match('/[\x00-\x08\x0E-\x1F\x7F]+/', $data);

would detect those.

Comment: No. By binary I do not mean control characters. I mean the dump of "binary" objects that you were trying to work with in your code. So far we have not found a nice way to do it - so we just control the dumping via a debug flag now. implementation here : https://github.com/rjha/webgloo/blob/master/lib/com/indigloo/Logger.php